# Reversing Date Values with MID

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range of dates that are continuing to output as US dates rather than Australian.
Example: 06/08/2021 (6th of August 2021) is outputting as 08/06/2021.

The solution I've found is to use MID to rearrange the month/day, but the below code doesn't seem to be working.

```
    Sub Reverse()

    For Each cell In Selection
    
OldDate = cell.Value
Newdate = Mid$(OldDate, 3, 2) & "/" & _
          Mid$(OldDate, 1, 1) & "/" & _
          Mid$(OldDate, 6, 4)
cell.Offset(0, 2) = Newdate

        Next
End Sub
```

With the above code, if the cell value was 08/02/2021, the offset output is still 08/02/2021.

However if I use the below:

```
Sub Reverse()

    For Each cell In Selection
    
OldDate = cell.Value

Newdate = Mid$(OldDate, 3, 2) & "/" & _
          Mid$(OldDate, 1, 1) & "/" & _
          Mid$(OldDate, 6, 4)

MsgBox Newdate

        Next
End Sub
```

Then a cell with a value of 08/02/2021 pops up in a message box correctly as 02/08/2021.

Can anyone please let me know what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using strings when you can just use a date variable and format it any way you like?

Comment: If your dates are numeric just change the number format to `MM/DD/YYYY`.

Comment: _what I'm doing wrong here?_ you are storing dates as text. Never do that, always use _Date_ (DateTime in SQL).

Comment: To add to that: if for some reason you need to store dates as a string, do it in a format that "naturally" sorts dates, e.g. YYYYMMDD. See also [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Comment: For a reason why @HelO'Ween suggested ISO 8601 see [here](https://xkcd.com/1179/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your dates are numeric just change the number format to `mm/dd/yyyy`.

```
Selection.NumberFormat = "mm\/dd\/yyyy"
```

If your dates are strings (text) then convert them to numeric dates so you can format them as you like:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function ConvertStringDDMMYYYYToDate(ByVal InputString As String) As Date
    'split string into 3 parts
    Dim DateArr As Variant
    DateArr = Split(InputString, "/")
    
    'create a real date out of the 3 parts
    ConvertStringDDMMYYYYToDate = DateSerial(DateArr(2), DateArr(1), DateArr(0))
End Function


Public Sub ConvertSelection()
    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In Selection
        Cell.Value = ConvertStringDDMMYYYYToDate(Cell.Text)
    Next Cell

    Selection.NumberFormat = "mm\/dd\/yyyy"
End Sub
```

If you want to validate your conversion use

```
Public Sub ConvertSelection()
    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In Selection
        Dim NumericDate As Date
        NumericDate = ConvertStringDDMMYYYYToDate(Cell.Text)
        
        If Format$(NumericDate, "dd\/mm\/yyyy") = Cell.Text Then  'validate if conversion was correct
            Cell.Value = ConvertStringDDMMYYYYToDate(Cell.Text)
        Else
            MsgBox "'" & Cell.Text & "' could not be converted properly.", vbExclamation
        End If
    Next Cell

    Selection.NumberFormat = "mm\/dd\/yyyy"
End Sub
```